# Pure Javascript - Select the properties of an unknown object based on user input with the fields he wants to be included in the output without any lib

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object and the user should be able to select only the properties that he/she wants.

Below is an example of an object that the user can filter;

```
const responseObject = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 25,
  cars: [
     {
         name: "Test car",
         brand: "Test brand",
         accessories: [
             {
                 name: "Test accessory",
                 description: "Test description",
                 code: "1234"
             },
             {
                 name: "Test accessory",
                 description: "Test description",
                 code: "12345"
             }
        ]
     },
     {
         name: "Test car 2",
         brand: "Test brand 2",
         accessories: [
             {
                 name: "Test accessory 2",
                 description: "Test description 2",
                 code: "1234"
             },
             {
                 name: "Test accessory 2",
                 description: "Test description",
                 code: "12345"
             }
        ]
     }
    ]
};
```

Below is an example of a user's request with the fields he/she wants to include in the response. It should work like a select (`SELECT name, cars.name, cars.accessories FROM ....`)

```
const includedFields = {
    fields: [
        "name",
        "cars.name",
        "cars.accessories."
    ]
};
```

This is the expected output. The code should only get the fields included in the user request and ignore all other fields from the input object. This object will come from an API:

```
const changedResponse = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  cars: [
     {
         name: "Test car",
         accessories: [
             {
                 name: "Test accessory",
             },
             {
                 name: "Test accessory",
             }
        ]
     },
     {
         name: "Test car 2",
         accessories: [
             {
                 name: "Test accessory 2"
             },
             {
                 name: "Test accessory 2"
             }
        ]
     }
    ]
};
```

This is the function I've created to try to solve the problem. I'm looping through all fields and checking if they are inside an array. If they aren't, I'll set them in the output, if they are I do not know what to do.

```js
function filterResponseFields(fieldsFilter, inputObject) { 
 const response = {};
 for(let i = 0; i < fieldsFilter.length; i++) {
   let fieldPath = fieldsFilter[i];
   let fieldPathAttributes = filter.split(".");
   let fieldsInsideArrays = [];
   let containsFieldIsInsideArray = false;
   let currentAttributePath = '';
   
   for(let j = 0; j < fieldsFilter.length; j++) {
       
    currentAttributePath = currentAttributePath ? fieldPathAttributes[j] : currentAttributePath + "." + fieldPathAttributes[j];
    if (Array.isArray(inputObject[currentAttributePath])) {
        containsFieldIsInsideArray = true;
        fieldsInsideArrays.push({
           path: currentAttributePath,
           filterField: filter
        });
    }
   }
   
   if (!containsFieldIsInsideArray) {
       response[field] = inputObject[field];
   } else {
       // I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
   }
}
```

Comment: Whaat you're trying to do is basically what [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the js `Object.keys` method to get all the keys of an objects, and then recursively call through the keys, appending the nested key as suffix like so :

```js
const responseObject = {
    name: 'Jhon Doe',
    age: 25,
    cars: [
       {
           name: "Test car",
           brand: "Test brand",
           acessories: [
               {
                   name: "Test acessory",
                   description: "Test description",
                   code: "1234"
               },
               {
                   name: "Test acessory",
                   description: "Test description",
                   code: "12345"
               }
          ]
       },
       {
           name: "Test car 2",
           brand: "Test brand 2",
           acessories: [
               {
                   name: "Test acessory 2",
                   description: "Test description 2",
                   code: "1234"
               },
               {
                   name: "Test acessory 2",
                   description: "Test description",
                   code: "12345"
               }
          ]
       }
    ]
};
  
const filterResponseFields = rawResponse => {
    const getFields = obj => Object.keys(obj).flatMap(key => {
        const value = obj[key]

        if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.length === 0 ? [] : getFields(value[0]).map(e => `${ key }.${ e }`)

        return typeof value === 'object' ? getFields(value).map(e => `${ key }.${ e }`) : key
    })

    const fields = getFields(rawResponse)

    return {
        fields
    }
}

console.log(filterResponseFields(responseObject))
```

By the way, if you want the user to only have some keys you can then filter the `fields` array.